# pyodbc - unable to update multiple items in row

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm attempting to update multiple items in a row, my code is as follows:

```
updateQuery = "UPDATE Throughput SET Test_Date = '%s' ,  Iperf11ntcpUL = '%s' , Iperf11ntcpDL = '%s' , Iperf11nudpUL = '%s' , Iperf11nudpDL = '%s' , HttpDL = '%s' , HttpUL = '%s', notes2='%s' where DeviceName = '%s' and Buildinfo ='%s' and Band = '%s' and Buildtype = '%s' " %(date, data['Iperf 11N TCP UL'], data['Iperf 11N TCP DL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP UL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP DL'], data['HTTP DL'],data['HTTP UL'],data['Notes'], data['Device Name'], data['Build Info / No.'], data['Band'], data['Build Type'])

cursor.execute(updateQuery)
```

I get the following error when this code is executed:

```
Previous SQL was not a query.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the problem myself.

I was executing my **updateQuery** within the following loop:

```
for row in cursor.execute(selectQuery)
```

instead, I grabbed the **id** from the row and after exiting the loop, I executed the update statement for the acquired id

Answer (score 2):

[Parameterize](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters) the update query:

```
...
update = """update Throughput
            set Test_Date = ?, Iperf11ntcpUL = ?, Iperf11ntcpDL = ?,  
                Iperf11nudpUL = ?, Iperf11nudpDL = ?, HttpDL = ?,
                HttpUL = ?, notes2 = ?
            where
                DeviceName = ? and Buildinfo = ? and
                Band = ? and Buildtype = ?;"""

parameters = [date, data['Iperf 11N TCP UL'], data['Iperf 11N TCP DL'],
              data['Iperf 11N UDP UL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP DL'],
              data['HTTP DL'], data['HTTP UL'], data['Notes'],
              data['Device Name'], data['Build Info / No.'],
              data['Band'], data['Build Type']]

cursor.execute(update, parameters)
...
```

Comment: How too deal with it if the column name & values are in a list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
updateQuery = "UPDATE Throughput SET Test_Date = '%s' ,  Iperf11ntcpUL = '%s' , Iperf11ntcpDL = '%s' , Iperf11nudpUL = '%s' , Iperf11nudpDL = '%s' , HttpDL = '%s' , HttpUL = '%s', notes2='%s' where DeviceName = '%s' and Buildinfo ='%s' and Band = '%s' and Buildtype = '%s' " %((date, data['Iperf 11N TCP UL'], data['Iperf 11N TCP DL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP UL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP DL'], data['HTTP DL'],data['HTTP UL'],data['Notes'], data['Device Name'], data['Build Info / No.'], data['Band'], data['Build Type']))
```

Everything after the '%' in your query (where you are putting values) is expected to be an array. Just wrap those values in parenthesis (see above)

Comment: What data values are you passing in?

Comment: data['Iperf 11N TCP UL'], data['Iperf 11N TCP DL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP UL'], data['Iperf 11N UDP DL'], data['HTTP DL'],data['HTTP UL'] are floats, date is a datetime object and data['Notes'] is a string. I did try changing the %s for the first 6 values to %f, but still no luck

Comment: Does the value in data['Notes'] contain an apostrophe? If so, you need to either remove it or replace it with a double apostrophe.

Comment: data['Notes'] = "Automated submission from IPerf Test Bed"